# SDL Camera and the background

Tags: c++, background, camera, sdl

Hello im working on a project using SDL library, im quite new to it and trying to get a hang of it...
Im not sure if its possible but im trying to make a background (map) that is independent to the camera. Lets say that background would be parent function to the camera and it would have its own coordinates, like lets say example League of Legends the map is loaded at the start of the game and every player, monster, etc. is updated its position and everything else and you move the camera freely on the map.
Right now I believe that your camera (the screen) is the parent and it has the coordinates of its own and it is actually background moving on the screen and not the camera moving on the map.
I would be really thankful for any help or the info on how to make that if its even possible.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial covers this and a multitude of other topics associated with game programming with SDL. http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/index.php